# Custom button toggle setting filterResourcesWithEvents ignores jquery text() call

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I would like to add a custom button to toggle the option filterResourcesWithEvents. Ideally the button would change style into a pressed state but for now I'm simply trying to change the button text after setting the option. The problem is that the text does not change.

One can find a full example here in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bsdz/pen/wNpYbB).

```
custom1: {
 text: 'Filter off',
 click: function() {
        var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
        var newFilterResourcesWithEvents = ! cal.option('filterResourcesWithEvents');
        cal.option('filterResourcesWithEvents', newFilterResourcesWithEvents);
        // The following line being ignored.
        $(this).text(newFilterResourcesWithEvents ? 'Filter on' : 'Filter off');
}},
```

I suspect the scheduler option function might be interferring with the text() update.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: your codepen link is broken

Comment: @ADyson fixed link. Thanks for spotting

Comment: Thanks. The Pen appears to be missing the fullCalendar Scheduler CSS file, which might account for the weird layout of the timeline. It's not affecting your other problem with the button, but just thought I'd mention it

Comment: Anyway I think the issue is that while your click function is running, something is re-drawing the whole calendar, including the button, and thus resetting its state. Possibly it's because you're running a filter.

Comment: You might be better off with something completely custom in the header such as a radio button / dropdown list which you provide, and isn't added through fullCalendar's custom button functionality. You can still inject content into the header bar yourself quite easily.

Comment: @ADyson That's true. Although I'm hoping there might be a workaround using FC's API so all my custom buttons are defined in a similar way. Also I wouldn't have to worry about replicating FC's button styles. That said, it might be the only option after I've tried email support .

Comment: might be worth seeing if you can set the button's state in either the viewRender or eventAfterAllRender callbacks and see it it's preserved. It would be after the calendar has been drawn, is my thinking. You can still check the filter option value at that time in the same way you do now. Meanwhile all your button click would do would be to set the filter option

Answer (score 1):

After a little experimentation I discovered if I use a class selector to change the button it just works. I'm not exactly sure why.

Basically if I replace the last line as:

`$("button.fc-custom1-button").text(newFilterResourcesWithEvents ? 'Filter on' : 'Filter off');`

I'm hoping that class naming remains consistent.